# Html,css -картинки по вертикали

Tags: html, css

**Нужно чтобы картинки были по центру**, но все ни как не получается...

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Planet N', arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ВЕРХНЯЯ ПАНЕЛЬ (ПОЛОСКА)*/

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: url(../img/1.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 41px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 41px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.titles__first {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.button {
  background: #fed136;
  color: #484543;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 115px;
}

.title h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title p {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.servises_item {
  width: 270px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.servises_item p {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.9em;
}

.servises_item h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.servises_item:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.servises_item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.servises {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#portfolio {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

#servises {
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.works img {
  float: left;
}

.works img:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.works img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.humble {
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.humble_item p {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.humble h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.humble_item img {
  margin-right: 200px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="humble">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Обо мне</h2>
      <p>
        Сейчас придумаю ...
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="humble clearfix">
      <div class="humble_item ">
        <img src="assets/img/about1.jpg">
        <img src="assets/img/about2.jpg">
        <img src="assets/img/about3.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="humble_item">
        <h2>July 2010</h2>
        <h2>Our humble beginnigs</h2>
        <p>TUTA PEZDA WASHE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="humble_item">
        <h2>Junaty 2011</h2>
        <h2>Our humble beginnigs</h2>
        <p>TUTA PEZDA WASHE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="humble_item">
        <h2>december 2012</h2>
        <h2>Our humble beginnigs</h2>
        <p>TUTA PEZDA WASHE</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример нормально посмотреть не получилось, так как у картинок инвалидный путь, но если вам необходимо какие-то блоки разместить по центру экрана, то это можно сделать так.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```